# In Moon, why wake up the second clone before the rescue team arrives?

Tags: moon-movie

The corporation should have waited and not woken up another clone in the meantime. The rescue team would have taken care of the first Sam (ie dispose of him) and then the second Sam would be woken up. You can't even blame corporate greed because they didn't let him out of the station in the meantime.

Comment: The title of this question is a major spoiler. I suggest editing it to make it more vague, and using spoiler markup in the body of the question.

Comment: Do we normally entertain questions about movies the asker openly admits they haven't bothered to watch themselves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty much unavoidable spoilers.

> There never was a rescue team.  The plan of the corporation was to indefinitely use clones to man the moon station for eternity.  There was no plan in place to rescue Sam.

So you might thenk ask what was really going on at this point.  Well...

> The cloning process is automated.  When Sam travelled out onto the lunar landscape, he was very close to the time when he was to be 'replaced'.  By not being there at the appropriate time, he avoided being 'sent back', and his clone was created in his absence as per the automatic process.  The corporation only finds out about this botch-up *after* the fact, and the alleged 'rescue' team is sent in to clean up after this mistake.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to explain a little better. I realize they weren't planning on rescuing the first Sam. I meant they could wait until the rescue team disposes of him and then only afterwards wake the second Sam. Then there would no chance of something going awry.

Comment: @user41956 Noted, and answer edited for clarity.  It was less that they weren't planning to rescue him, and more that they weren't planning on there *ever* being more than one Sam, and only found out about it after the accident that led to him missing his 'departure'.

Comment: Ha, I guess I should've watched the movie :-) I just read the plot and couldn't figure this point out

Answer (score 1):

Sam I was having hallucinations and chest pain before he went out on the surface. He crashed his rover because he had another hallucination, thus GERTY (the computer) probably assumes that he has died and woke up Sam II to take his place.
Sam II then tricks GERTY to let him go outside, finds the body of Sam I and brings it back to the base.
The reason to use clones was because it is very expensive to travel to the Moon, so there would have not been any rescue/cleanup mission; the corporation would have probably instructed GERTY to keep Sam II from the area of the accident and that would've been it.